# Django Admin: Determine correct image upload path

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls, django-1.10

I am new to Django and I am currently having problems in showing uploaded images in Django Admin. I have followed many posted Q and A here in stackoverflow but of those worked in my problem. I hope any active of the coding ninja here could help me with this problem. Here is the detailed view of the problem:

1. I have defined the MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in *settings.py*

   ```
   BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
   MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
   ```
2. This is my upload model in *models.py*:

   ```
   from django.utils.html import mark_safe

   class ImageDetails(models.Model):
       image = models.ImageField(null=True)    

       def image_img(self):
           if self.image:
               return mark_safe('<img src="%s" height="125px" width="125px"/>' % (self.image.url))
           else:
               return '(No image found)'
       image_img.short_description = 'Thumbnail'
   ```
3. In my Application *urls.py*:

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^inputImage', views.inputImage, name='inputImage'),
       url(r'', views.index),
   ]
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   ```
4. In my admin.py:

   ```
   class ImageDetailsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       fields = ["image"]  #for file upload
       list_display = ("image_img",)

   admin.site.register(ImageDetails, ImageDetailsAdmin)
   ```

The image was successfully stored at *ProjectDIR/media*. The HTML returns the url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/imagename.jpg at img tag. But the page fails to load the image (I will be redirected to index page whenever when using the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/imagename.jpg). I am using Django version 1.10

Comment: Check MEDIA_URL - you have assigned twice. I think you meant to use MEDIA_ROOT in the first occurrence.

Comment: Opps. that was actually media root in the original code here. Done editing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected, this problem is about URLs in Django. The problem occurred because I declared the following urlpattern in an app urls.py:

```
     url(r'', views.index, name='index'),
```

I solved the problem by changing the code to:

```
     url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

And adding the following code at the project's main urls.py:

```
    if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```